# Fundametal Group and Étale Fundamental Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

1. For what kind of schemes the fundamental group and the étale fundamental group coincide?
2. Is there a relation between this groups on a variety?

I'm interested on toric varieties (more generally, varieties with torus action).
Any commentary will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2.) There is a short exact sequence (of profinite groups) relating these groups.

Comment: Is your toric variety over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: yeah. its a toric variety over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What's true is that $\widetilde{\pi_1(X^{\text{an}})}\cong \pi_1^{\text{et}}(X)$ for a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-variety. This follows essentially from the Riemann existence theorem. This is about as good as you get since, as Qiaochu Yuan said in another recent thread, every irreducible sober space is contractible. So, every irreducible scheme is contractible.